# Occupancy (motion) switch wiring question

Tags: wiring, switch

I have a single-pole light switch that I want to replace with a motion-detecting occupancy light. It is a Leviton Motion Sensor, # IPS02.

When I removed the old switch, I noticed that the switch only had two black wires connected to it, plus the ground. When I hooked up the wires to the new switch, it didn't function. Do I just need to switch the wire locations on the new switch? Or am I missing something here...

Comment: What is the make and model of the occupancy switch? It's common for them to need a grounded (neutral) conductor connected as well, to function.  Have you read the documentation that came with the device, it typically has instructions and wiring diagrams.

Comment: If you had only two wires on the existing switch, three total with the ground, it's unlikely that it will work without a grounded conductor (neutral). You can likely tell simply by the fact that it takes two screws to switch the circuit and a green screw for the ground, if there's more screws it's probably a safe bet it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for the [switch you're using](http://www.leviton.com/OA_HTML/ProductDetail.jsp?partnumber=IPS02-1LW&section=38557&minisite=10251), a grounded (neutral) conductor is not required.  The wiring diagram for your device looks like this

[image: Wiring diagram for Leviton’s IPV02/IPS02 Universal Vacancy and Occupancy Sensor]

If your device isn't working, it's possible that you've reversed the wires. Make sure the black wire from the switch is connected to the **line** wire, and the red wire is connected to the **load** wire.

If the switch still does not function, verify that the grounding conductor is solidly connected, and that the ground is good.

If the switch still does not function, the device may be defective and need to be replaced.

Comment: There is no red wire. Only two black wires. I need to test to see if one of them is an unmarked load. I'll post back if I have luck...

Comment: There's not a red wire coming out of the switch?

Comment: Note that this type of switch requires being able to run a trickle current thru the load even when off, and may not work well with LED or CFL bulbs.